# React Stack Navigator V5 does not response when headerMode="float"

Tags: react-native, navigation, navigation-drawer, stack-navigator

im useing react-native-drawer v5, and in the header i have hamburger icon.
when headerMode!=float -> its worked like expected and open and close the drawer.

when i change to headerMode="float", the header is not response to the click, and nothing happend,

- note that im checking it on Android device. I dont need to know about IOS..

here my stack and drawer nav:

```
     import...
const MainStack = createStackNavigator();
    const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const stackScreenOptions = {
cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forHorizontalIOS,

gestureEnabled: true,
gestureDirection: "horizontal",
headerTitleAlign: "center",
headerStyle: {
    borderBottomWidth: 0.5,
    elevation: 2,
    borderColor: "white",
    backgroundColor: "#1d2731",
    height: 82,
},
headerTitleStyle: {
    color: "white",
},
};

   const MainStackScreen = ({ navigation }) => (
 <MainStack.Navigator headerMode="float" screenOptions={stackScreenOptions}>/////////HERE THE PROBLEM OCCURE -> when i declare headerMode="float
    <MainStack.Screen
        name="Main"
        component={MainScreen}
        options={{
            title: "ליאור",
            headerLeft: () => (
                <Icon
                    style={{ position: "absolute", left: 15 }}
                    name="bars"
                    color="white"
                    size={30}
                    onPress={() => {
                        navigation.openDrawer();
                    }}
                />
            ),
        }}
    />
    <MainStack.Screen name="MeetingPicker" component={MeetingPicker} />
    <MainStack.Screen name="MyMeetings" component={UserHistory} />
    <MainStack.Screen name="About" component={AboutScreen} />
    <MainStack.Screen name="Gallery" component={GalleryScreen} />
    <MainStack.Screen name="Location" component={LocationScreen} />
    <MainStack.Screen name="Logout" component={LogoutModal} />
</MainStack.Navigator>
);

export const DrawerNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <Drawer.Navigator drawerStyle={styles.drawerStyle} drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent {...props} />}>
            <Drawer.Screen name="Main" component={MainStackScreen} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
    );
};
```

Comment: Are you on latest version of stack?

Comment: Yes "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.11.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.12.8",